# VBA code for new mail alert in Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Need VBA code/script to include in an Outlook rule triggered by new mail that forwards an email containing ONLY the sender email address and subject to an external email address.

Comment: We’d love to help you. but first please visit read understand the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VBA macro sub should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
    ' here you can do whatever you need
End Sub
```

You need to check out the [SenderEmailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868262.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the incoming email. It returns a string that represents the e-mail address of the sender of the Outlook item.

The [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff865652.aspx) property returns a string indicating the subject for the Outlook item.

The [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399.aspx) method executes the Forward action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MailItem object.

Finally, see [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).